# Comparison of two string arrays in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I have two different NumPy string arrays. I need to compare it and to find which elements from first array are absent in second array. And I also want to use LIKE operator for comparison. What is the short way to do this?

Comment: There is no "LIKE" operator in Python.  How do you want the comparison to work?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know. But "LIKE" is not obligatory condition.

Comment: Do you need to preserve order or multiplicity?

Comment: No, it's not necessary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there is no LIKE operator, all I can do is answer the "find which elements from first array are absent in second array" part of the question.  If you don't need to preserve order or multiplicity, you can do this using 
[`np.setdiff1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html):

```
>>> s0 = np.array(['e', 'a','bc','e', 'd'])
>>> s1 = np.array(['a','d'])
>>> np.setdiff1d(s0,s1)
array(['bc', 'e'], 
      dtype='|S2')
```